# Multiply dataframe column with a factor from a list, that is chosen based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have daily airport arrival and departure numbers which I want to downsample to hourly data based on factors for each hour. I have my hourly factors in a list, for example:

```
       factors = {  0: 0.1,
                    1: 0.3,
                    2: 0.5,
                    3: 0.1,}
```

Traffic data is in a dataframe, currently with DateTimeIndex for every hour, with padded values (e.g. 300 movements per day, this entry is present for every hour now).

```
    datum                  daily
    2018-01-01 00:00:00    306
    2018-01-01 01:00:00    306
    2018-01-01 02:00:00    306
    2018-01-01 03:00:00    306
```

I tried to put the hour into a new column with

```
    df['hour'] = df.index.hour
```

and then create a new column `new_scaled`, where I want to multiply the daily value with the factor for this particular hour that I want to get from the list.

```
    df['new_scaled'] = df.daily*factors[df.hour]
```

I get an error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.

When I try to access the factor from the list directly with `df.index.hour`, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Int64Index'`

How can I access the factor from the list to calculate the new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map),

```
factors = {0: 0.1, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.1}

df['datum']  = pd.to_datetime(df.datum)

df['new_scaled']  = df.datum.dt.hour.map(factors) * df.daily
```

---

```
                datum  daily  new_scaled
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00    306        30.6
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00    306        91.8
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00    306       153.0
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00    306        30.6
```